# Saving images(base64) to db (nodejs + postgres) and returning them to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, api, filesystems

I want to save base64 (I already converted it on server side) to db. I successfully did it, but I want to return them to client side by GET request.

The problem is when I decode base64 format to File(I need to send to client side File, not base64).

The best solution I found is to use fs.writeFile function, that saves file to disk(nodejs folder). But the flow looks bad: By GET request I need to get base64 from DB,convert it to File, save File to nodejs folder, then send File to client side and then delete this File from nodejs folder.

Maybe anybody can optimize this solution without saving files to nodejs folder? Thanks :)